# Custom function for aggregates in slickgrid

Tags: slickgrid

Is it possible that we can aggregate based on a custom function in slick grid?

For example, we have 3 columns A,B,C, the aggregate for C is calculated as follows

sum(abs(A)*C)/sum(abs(A))

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you an definitely do that. The easiest way is to create a new aggregator object.

Check out: http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-grouping.html

Copy an existing aggregator in `Slick.DataView.js` and mod it.